# MySql Query To Find Sum Of Repeat Count

Tags: mysql

I have a table which looks like:

```
Name
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
C
C
D
E
F
F
F
G
```

On above table if I try to execute following repeat query:

```
select Name as Name,count(Name) as Repeat_Count
    from call_data 
    GROUP BY 1  
HAVING (Repeat_Count > 1);
```

My result coming as:

```
Name    Repeat_Count
A           4
B           4
C           2
D           1
E           1
F           3
G           1
```

However I want your guys help to get sum of **Repeat_Count** column.....as per above sample my output will be **16**

It will be great if anyone can share a query to execute what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: do you want only 16 output of all else indivisual count ??

Comment: Yes, I want outcome as 16 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name,sum(repeat_count) from
(select Name as Name,count(Name) as Repeat_Count
    from call_data 
    GROUP BY 1  
HAVING (Repeat_Count > 1))temp;
```

Will return 16 for all records in name column
is this what you want ?